# My JS does not change class name

Tags: javascript, html

I am frustrated. Here is my js and html code. The js works well with other elements except the one with id="logo". It doesn't change the class name.

HTML:

```
<body class="beforepace">
<div id="golden" onmouseover="showdesc('golden-desc','golden');" onmouseout="hidedesc('golden-desc','golden');">
<div id="golden-desc" class="desc">Golden</div>
</div>
<div id="utopia" onmouseover="showdesc('utopia-desc','utopia');" onmouseout="hidedesc('utopia-desc','utopia');">
<div id="utopia-desc" class="desc">Utopia</div>
</div>
<div id="logo" class="default"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
// JavaScript Document
var logo=document.getElementById("logo");
function showdesc(a,b){
    logo.className=b;
    document.getElementById(a).classList.add("desc_show");
    document.getElementById(b).classList.add("div-hover");
}
function hidedesc(a,b){
    document.getElementById(a).classList.remove("desc_show");
    document.getElementById(b).classList.remove("div-hover");
    if(b==="golden")document.getElementById("logo").classList.remove("golden");
    else if(b==="utopia")document.getElementById("logo").classList.remove("utopia");
}
```

Please help me and thank you very much!

Comment: Could you be more descriptive of the problem? Your code already sets classNames to `logo` while hovering on `golden` or `utopia`.

Comment: where did you import your js file?

Comment: What did stepping through the debugger show you?

Answer (score 0):

you can check color change of logo div

```js
// JavaScript Document
var logo=document.getElementById("logo");
function showdesc(a,b){ 
    logo.className=b; 
    document.getElementById(a).classList.add("desc_show");
    document.getElementById(b).classList.add("div-hover");
}
function hidedesc(a,b){  
    document.getElementById(a).classList.remove("desc_show");
    document.getElementById(b).classList.remove("div-hover");
    if(b==="golden")document.getElementById("logo").classList.remove("golden");
    else if(b==="utopia")document.getElementById("logo").classList.remove("utopia");
}
```

```css
#logo{
  padding-top:10px;
  }
.golden{
  color:yellow;
  }
.utopia{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<body class="beforepace">
<div id="golden" onmouseover="showdesc('golden-desc','golden');" onmouseout="hidedesc('golden-desc','golden');">
<div id="golden-desc" class="desc">Golden</div>
</div>
<div id="utopia" onmouseover="showdesc('utopia-desc','utopia');" onmouseout="hidedesc('utopia-desc','utopia');">
<div id="utopia-desc" class="desc">Utopia</div>
</div>
<div id="logo" class="default">logo here</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> For add new class use this

```
$("#logo").addClass("yourClassName");
```

> For remove existing class use this

```
 $("#logo").removeClass("yourClassName");
```

Comment: I think using `.classList.add` to add class is OK.